# Did Jesus say to preach to Gentiles, or not?

Tags: life-of-jesus, paul-apostle, evangelism, gentile

Besides Paul, who never met Christ, was Jesus' message ever meant to be told to the Gentiles?

Comment: Paul never met Christ?? Have you read Acts 9? Even aside from that, as a leading Pharisee it's pretty unlikely that they never crossed paths before.

Comment: This question could have many different answers, depending on the perspective and denominational affiliation of the answerer. Questions here should be more specifically and objectively answerable. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: While I agree this question might use some additional context, I'm okay with it not asking from a particular denominational perspective, as it is straightforward and practical - it would be difficult to put theology into this question.  If there are truly different camps here, then that it would great to explain that with a survey answer and enlighten us all...

Answer (score 13):

Jesus told the disciples to preach the Gospel to all nations.

> Go therefore and make disciples of **all nations**, baptizing them in
>   the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit (Matthew
>   28:19, ESV)
>
> But you will receive power when the Holy Spirit has come upon you, and
>   you will be my witnesses in Jerusalem and in all Judea and Samaria,
>   and **to the end of the earth**.” (Acts 1:8, ESV)

**Paul wasn't the first one nor the only one who preached the Gospel to the Gentiles**. According to Acts, **Peter was the first** to preach the Gospel to the Gentiles. Peter received a vision from the Lord and received a command to preach to the Gentiles in the house of Cornelius the gentile. The Gentiles were filled with the Holy Spirit and were baptized.

> While Peter was still saying these things, the Holy Spirit fell on all
>   who heard the word. And the believers from among the circumcised who
>   had come with Peter were amazed, because the gift of **the Holy Spirit
>   was poured out even on the Gentiles**. For they were hearing them
>   speaking in tongues and extolling God. Then Peter declared, “Can
>   anyone withhold water for baptizing these people, who have received
>   the Holy Spirit just as we have?” And he commanded them to be baptized
>   in the name of Jesus Christ. Then they asked him to remain for some
>   days. (Acts 10:44-47, ESV)

Peter reported this to the believers in Jerusalem and they all glorified God.

> When they heard these things they fell silent. And they glorified God,
>   saying, “Then to the Gentiles also God has granted repentance that
>   leads to life.” (Acts 11:18, ESV)

Comment: So while alive Jesus never tried to preach to other besides the lost sheep of the house of Israel?

Comment: @josetapadas Not exactly. Jesus was also preaching in Samaria  but I'm not sure Samaritans are gentiles or not.

Comment: @josetapadas Just to add to Mawia's great answer:

     John 10:16  KJV   And other sheep I have, which are not of this fold: them also I must bring, and they shall hear my voice; and there shall be one fold, and one shepherd. 

Jesus wanted to first save the Jews, but later included the Gentiles as Mawia  said in the great commission.

     Matthew 23:37  KJV  O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, thou that killest the prophets, and stonest them which are sent unto thee, how often would I have gathered thy children together, even as a hen gathereth her chickens under her wings, and ye would not!

Comment: @josetapadas You may be interested in this account in Matthew: http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%208:5-13

Comment: @josetapadas there were a delegation of Greeks who came to see Jesus. John 12:20-22. So it is reasonable to believe that Jesus ministered to Gentiles.

Comment: But if all the people were amazed that the Holy Spirit was poured out even on the Gentiles, that would mean that the Great Commission, Matthew 28:19, was a later addition--for they would not have been amazed at preaching to Gentiles if Jesus had already commanded them to do just that.  (Also, Samaritans were Israelites, and AFAIK Jewish except for disagreeing with Jesus' sect of Judaism over where sacrifices should be made: Mount Gerizim or Mount Zion.)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, He talked about it after His resurrection:

> Go ye therefore, and make disciples of **all the nations**, baptizing them
> into the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit:
>
> Teaching them to observe all things whatsoever I commanded you: and
> lo, I am with you always, even unto the end of the world. **Matthew
> 28:19-20 ASV**

Comment: and how about before He died?

Answer (score 1):

**Did Jesus say to preach to Gentiles, or not?**

Most of the preaching Jesus did was to Israel announcing that the kingdom of heaven was at hand.

> Matthew 4:17  From that time Jesus began to preach, and to say,
>   Repent: for the kingdom of heaven is at hand.

This was because Israel had been promised a king and a kingdom and Jesus came to offer that kingdom to Israel with a new covenant.

> Jerimiah 31:31-32  Behold, the days come, saith the LORD, that I will
>   make a new covenant with the house of Israel, and with the house of
>   Judah:   Not according to the covenant that I made with their fathers
>   in the day that I took them by the hand to bring them out of the land
>   of Egypt; which my covenant they brake, although I was an husband unto
>   them, saith the LORD:

Nothing Jesus ever said hinted that he knew Israel would drop the ball and that the kingdom would be delayed for over 2,000 years. In the “Great Commission” Jesus tells the disciples what the expected role for Israel is to be.

> Mark 16:15-18  And he said unto them, Go ye into all the world, and
>   preach the gospel to every creature.   He that believeth and is
>   baptized shall be saved; but he that believeth not shall be damned.
>   And these signs shall follow them that believe; In my name shall they
>   cast out devils; they shall speak with new tongues;   They shall take
>   up serpents; and if they drink any deadly thing, it shall not hurt
>   them; they shall lay hands on the sick, and they shall recover.

As far as the gentiles go, we have a hint that they were to be included.

> John 12:20-24  And there were certain Greeks among them that came up
>   to worship at the feast:   The same came therefore to Philip, which
>   was of Bethsaida of Galilee, and desired him, saying, Sir, we would
>   see Jesus.   Philip cometh and telleth Andrew: and again Andrew and
>   Philip tell Jesus.   And Jesus answered them, saying, The hour is
>   come, that the Son of man should be glorified.   Verily, verily, I say
>   unto you, Except a corn of wheat fall into the ground and die, it
>   abideth alone: but if it die, it bringeth forth much fruit.

From this we might conclude that Jesus was saying that there was a harvest to be had among the gentiles, but that it had to wait until his resurrection.

Comment: What about the Samaritan woman and town that he preached to, many of them accepting him as Messiah?  Also, the answer would be better if you edit to answer it directly at the start (yes, no, or maybe...) and then expound.  Most of the answer I am thinking that your answer is no, then you only really address the question at the end.

Answer (score -3):

If Jesus meant for his disciples to go to all nations and preach the gospel to Gentiles, why did Peter need a vision in Acts 10 to visit Cornelius, a Gentile (actually a proselyte of the gate)?  Why did Peter tell Cornelius it was an unlawful thing for him, a Jew, to be in the house of a Gentile?

Because Jesus in His earthly ministry was strictly preaching to "the lost sheep of the house of Israel".  Salvation to the world, apart from the nation of Israel, was not revealed until the ascended Christ shared this "mystery" with the Apostle Paul.  The apostle Paul is THE apostle of the Gentiles (ROM 11:8 KJV).  The "mystery" revealed is revealed in Ephesians 3.  Rightly divided the word of truth (II TIM 2:15) and you will see Paul's unique authority and apostleship.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Though you do speak of related matters, this answer doesn't focus on the question, which is specifically *not* about Paul's preaching, but about Jesus' message and whether it was meant to be told to the Gentiles. See: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer). Meanwhile, I do hope you'll stick around and browse some of the other questions and answers here.